# The operator & is undefined for the argument types BlockState, int

Tags: int, minecraft

I am trying to fix my minecraft mod. Now in the line :
int blockMetaWithoutPoweredBit = state & 0x7;
It is saying that : the operator & is undefined for the argument types BloxkState, int. Before Minecraft used mostly "int", now they changed it to BlockState which replaces all "int" because BlockState has them in its code. How can I fix this?
I have tried a lot of things to fix it myself but sadly I have failed
Block states are extra pieces of data that further define a block..

```
public void onMinecartPass(World world, EntityMinecart cart, BlockPos pos)
{
    //cm = blockID
    if (world.getBlockState(pos) == ERMBase.monorailPowered)
    {
        BlockState state = getBlockState();

        if ((Boolean)state.equals(POWERED))
        {
            double var24 = Math.sqrt(cart.motionX * cart.motionX + cart.motionZ * cart.motionZ);

            if (var24 < 0.03D)
            {
                cart.motionX *= 0.0D;
                cart.motionY *= 0.0D;
                cart.motionZ *= 0.0D;
            }
            else
            {
                cart.motionX *= 0.5D;
                cart.motionY *= 0.0D;
                cart.motionZ *= 0.5D;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int blockMetaWithoutPoweredBit = state & 0x7;
            double var41 = Math.sqrt(cart.motionX * cart.motionX + cart.motionZ * cart.motionZ);

            if (var41 > 0.01D)
            {
                double var43 = 0.06D;
                cart.motionX += cart.motionX / var41 * var43;
                cart.motionZ += cart.motionZ / var41 * var43;
            }
            else if (blockMetaWithoutPoweredBit == 1)
            {
                if (world.isBlockIndirectlyGettingPowered(pos) == pos.getX() - 1)
                {
                    cart.motionX = 0.02D;
                }
                else if (world.isBlockIndirectlyGettingPowered(pos) == pos.getX() + 1)
                {
                    cart.motionX = -0.02D;
                }
            }
            else if (blockMetaWithoutPoweredBit == 0)
            {
                if (world.isBlockIndirectlyGettingPowered(pos) == pos.getZ() - 1)
                {
                    cart.motionZ = 0.02D;
                }
                else if (world.isBlockIndirectlyGettingPowered(pos) == pos.getZ() + 1)
                {
                    cart.motionZ = -0.02D;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the definition of `BlockState` and tell us the entire error message. Do not try to paraphrase the error message, tell us the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
state & 0x7;
```

which is trying to compare an int and a BlockState object, you need to be using the & operator on two ints.

Comment: Yes but the BlockState object must be there, so i have to do something with the int but I dont know what.

Comment: So I guess no one else has any suggestions.

Comment: I looked into the bukkit source code a bit, where is getBlockState() defined? This is all very framework dependent, it sounds to me like they updated so you don't need to use a bit mask anymore.